# case when but two columns instead of one column

Tags: sql-server

I need some advice and suggestions if there is available some way of doing something like this:

```
SELECT Status=Case 
WHEN clflf.product='active' 
THEN 'Active' ELSE 'NotActive' END;
```

this basically creates active or notactive in one column.

Is there some way of doing a case when or some other technique so that I can have two columns, 'Active' and 'NotActive'?

Comment: Yes write two separate case statements. One with `clflf.product='active'`  and one with `clflf.product<>'active'`

Comment: Do you even search for your question? [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-cl/library/ms181765.aspx) first google result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need separate case statements, like so.

```
Select StatusActive = Case when clflf.product='active' then 1 ELSE 0 end
    ,StatusNotActive = Case when clflf.product <>'active' then 1 ELSE 0 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do

```
SELECT active,
       1 - active AS notactive
FROM   clflf
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE
                             WHEN clflf.product = 'active' THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                           END) CA(active)
```